# Python match case(switch) invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3.7.3.
all documentation is points to this being the correct way to do a switch statement in python. Not sure why it's not working. Am I supposed to import match?
syntax error below.

```
    match player:
               ^
```

```
def evaluate(player, ai):
    match player:
        case Choice.rock:
            if ai == Choice.rock:
                return "draw"
            elif ai == Choice.scissors:
                return "player wins"
            elif ai == Choice.paper:
                return "ai wins"
        case Choice.paper:
            if ai == Choice.rock:
                return "player wins"
            elif ai == Choice.scissors:
                return "ai wins"
            elif ai == Choice.paper:
                return "draw" 
        case Choice.scissors:
            if ai == Choice.rock:
                return "ai wins"
            elif ai == Choice.scissors:
                return "draw"
            elif ai == Choice.paper:
                return "player wins"
```

Comment: `match` was added in python 3.10

Answer (score 3):

`match` requires python version >= 3.10, see [what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html)